# How do access and assign value for an int pointer datatype on struct?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

If i want to give a value to int *num2, how would i do this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    struct az {
        int num1;
        int *num2;
    };
    struct az test;
    test.num1 =20;
    printf("\n %d",test.num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you unsure how to deal with an `int*` member variable of a `struct` or an `int*` variable by itself?

Comment: You would assign it in the same way you assign any other value. With the assignment (`=`) operator. Perhaps you mean *what* you should assign to it. Of course we can't answer that as only you can decide what the program should do (in the same way we can't tell you that `num1` should be `30` and not `20`). The only thing we can say is that the value needs to be an `int` pointer. Common sources: `malloc` call or address of an existing `int` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`int *num2;` is a pointer to some place in the memory that contains an `int` value. Since you just declare a pointer without any memory allocating, it is simply points to nothing (or random place).

You have to allocate memory then assign a value to this memory:

```
test.num2 =new int(20);
```

However, do not forget to delete this allocated memory when you finish:

```
delete test.num2;
```

The real question here, do you really want that pointer here? probably not.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value to the integer that `test.num2` points to, you must de-reference the pointer with an asterisk, like so:

```
test.num2 = new int(20); // Allocates memory and sets the pointer to this memory
*(test.num2) = 10; // Assign a value of 10 to the int that test.num2 points to
```

To assign an address to the pointer, you must either assign another pointer to it, or assign it's value by referencing an int with an ampersand:

```
test.num2 = new int(20); // Allocates memory and sets the pointer to this location
int *ptr = new int(10);
delete test.num2; // Free memory that test.num2 pointed to
test.num2 = ptr // Makes test.num2 point to the same int as ptr
int x = 10;
test.num2 = &x; // Makes test.num2 point to x
```

Comment: *(test.num2) = 20; This is UB. You have to allocate memory first

Comment: Please do not mix new and free in the same code. malloc&&free || new&&delete

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `num2` in the same way as `num1`. Of course, since it's not an `int` but an `int*`, you can't assign `20` to it - you can assign the address of some `int` variable instead:

```
struct az {
    int num1;
    int *num2;
};
struct az test;
test.num1 = 20;

int i;
test.num2 = &i;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example *num2* is typically used as a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. However, neither *num2* nor *num1* is a good name in this case. Let's instead declare our dynamic array type as a record with the fields *length* and *items*:

```
struct Array {
   int length;
   int *items;
};
typedef struct Array Array;
```

If we have a variable *a* of type *Array*, before we can assign values to its elements we must first allocate memory for the array. In C this is typically done with the function *malloc*. This function, however, is rather error prone to use so it's a good idea to define a macro function which simplifies memory allocation:

```
#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) (ptr) = malloc((n) * sizeof (ptr)[0])
```

After having called *NEW_ARRAY* we can assign values to the array:

```
int length;
Array a;

length = 20;
a.length = length;
NEW_ARRAY(a.items, length);
a.items[0] = 37;
a.items[1] = 19;
...
```

When we are done with the array we can release the memory used by the elements:

```
free(a.items);
```